# Contour Integrals

Tags: math-mode

I know that `\oint` gives a closed line integral sign, but how do you make the same with a double integral instead? I tried `\ooint` and `\oiint` but neither worked.

EDIT: Also what would the corresponding commands for triple integrals be? And is there a way to do higher-order integrals (4,5,...)? Cheers!

Comment: Try `\oiint` with `\usepackage{wasysym}`.

Comment: @AdamLiter How do I decide between all these packages?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `esint`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \oiint x
  \]
  \[
  \varoiint x
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pxfonts}  %% or txfonts  or mathabx
\begin{document}
  \[
  \oiint x
  \]
  \[
  \oiiint x
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}  
\begin{document}
  \[
  \oiint x
  \]
  \[
  \oiiint x
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything for triple integrals? I don't really need higher than that.

Comment: @user51108 I have added few possibilities.

Comment: Ah how do I decide!?!? And will that change what my integrals look like? And I tried finding these on dexterify but it didn't work, how do you find them (or do you just know cause you know this stuff)?

Comment: @user51108 You can search in: http://ctan.imsc.res.in/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf . The fonts will certainly change many things. You should be cautious.

Comment: If you want to use only one symbol, then search in this site. There are answers that explain how to use only one (or more) symbol(s) without loading the full package.